# Auto-reloading files in Scala/Lift/SBT .11?

Tags: scala, jetty, lift, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

In SBT .7, you could do

```
~jetty-run
```

in order to get your files to auto compile and reload the web app whenever something changes. In SBT .11, You can do

```
~container:start
```

which also re-compiles files, but does not seem to reload the web app, everytime something changes. Rather, I have to do a

```
container:stop
container:start
```

to see the changes. The problem with this is that it takes `~30s` for the it all to restart. Is there a better way of doing it? Digging through google and SBT has not found me any answers

EDIT:
doing a

```
container:start
container:reload
```

each time something changes, seems to work well. However, is it possible to make it happen automatically in that sequence? Something like:

```
~(container:start, container:reload)
```

which doesn't work, but i wish it did

Comment: See if this question is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469503/sbt-0-11-2-how-to-combine-copy-resources-with-aux-compile

Answer (score 44, accepted):

So it turns out the answer is that ~ can take a command list, as was mentioned in the link fmpwizard left. Hence you can do

```
~;container:start; container:reload /
```

does the correct thing: each time I save the files, it recompiles the necessary files and reloads the web app!

EDIT: should be container:reload, as mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: +1, I believe you meant, "~;container:start; container:reload /", I get an error with "container reload". The former does the trick nicely in a Scala/SBT/Spray project...

Comment: Is there any way to do this that keeps the user logged in? It's a pain to have to log in again every time I change a file.

Comment: @phopkins yes you need to add extended sessions to your application : https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Extended_Sessions

Answer (score 1):

`~container:start` is not needed ,
you can use first `container:start` without `~` , and then `~container:reload` , so `container:start` isn't relaunched  after every code change .. i think

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something like :

```
container:start
~compile
```

Comment: Tried that; it compiles it each time but does not reload the app =(